# Create different event handlers for different levels in a grid in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, c1flexgrid

I am using a DataTree Grid from ComponentOne.  Currently, the DataTree grid has 2 levels (Parent & Child).  Each row in each grid has a Checkbox column that the user can 'Select' the row.  When the user selects the Parent Row is fires the event, flexgrid_CellChecked.  When the child grid is selected, the event fired is flexgrid_ChildCellChecked.  I want to add a 3rd level to the DataTree and a corresponding event that fires when the Checkbox in the innermost grid is selected.  Let's call it flexgrid_ChildChildCellChecked.

This events are instantiated during the Expand (int row) Method in the DataTree class.  The problem is when the first child (level 2) is expanded, the events ChildCellChecked and ChildChildCellChecked can be added as handlers.  When the second child (level 3) is expanded, both of these events are null.

This is the DataTree class with the Expand method:

```
public class C1FlexDataTree : C1FlexGrid, ISupportInitialize
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #region ** fields

    // reference to hidden column that contains details rows for each master record
    //
    // this is created automatically by a DataSet based on its Relations.
    //
    // e.g. if the parent table is 'Orders', this could be an 'OrderDetails' table 
    // with the order details for each order on the master data table.
    //
    private Column _colChild = null;

    // child grid that displays the headers rows over the native header rows.
    //
    // this grid appears on top of all child controls and prevents children from
    // hiding the parent grid's header rows when they scroll.
    //
    private GridHeader _hdr = null; // <<1.1>>
// fire event to allow setting up child grids
    // the event sender is the child grid that was just bound
    public event EventHandler SetupColumns;
    public event RowColEventHandler ChildCellChecked;
    public event RowColEventHandler ChildChildCellChecked;

    protected virtual void OnSetupColumns(object sender)
    {
        if (SetupColumns != null)
            SetupColumns(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected virtual void OnChildCellChecked(object sender, RowColEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChildCellChecked != null)
        {
            ChildCellChecked(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnChildChildCellChecked(object sender, RowColEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChildChildCellChecked != null)
        {
            ChildChildCellChecked(sender, e);
        }
    }
    // get top-level grid (overall parent)
    public C1FlexDataTree ParentGrid
    {
        get
        {
            C1FlexDataTree parent = this;
            while (parent.Parent is C1FlexDataTree)
                parent = parent.Parent as C1FlexDataTree;
            return parent;
        }
    }
// expand row
    public bool ExpandRow(int row)
    {
        // sanity
        if (row < Rows.Fixed || row >= Rows.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check that the row is not already expanded
        C1FlexDataTree childGrid = Rows[row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
        if (childGrid != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check that we have a data source for this row
        object dataSource = _colChild != null? _colChild[row] : null;
        if (!(dataSource is IBindingList))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // ** fire before collapse event
        var e = new RowColEventArgs(row, -1);
        OnBeforeCollapse(e);
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // add node row (unbound) to display child
        Rows.InsertNode(row + 1, -1);

        // make new row non-editable (it's just a placeholder)
        Rows[row + 1].AllowEditing = false;

        // create child grid
        childGrid = new C1FlexDataTree();
        childGrid.Visible = false;
        childGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal;



            // hook up event handlers
           //When there is only 2 levels this 'if' statement is not needed.
           //But with 3 levels, the ChildCellChecked is null
            if (ChildCellChecked != null)
            {
                childGrid.CellChecked += new RowColEventHandler(ChildCellChecked);

        }

        // attach child grid to parent, set data source
        Controls.Add(childGrid);
        childGrid.DataSource = dataSource;

        // save references: 
        // child grid Tag property contains a reference to the parent row
        // parent row UserData contains a reference to the child grid
        childGrid.Tag = Rows[row];
        Rows[row].UserData = childGrid;

        // make child grid visible, move it into position
        childGrid.Visible = true;
        childGrid.UpdatePosition();
        childGrid.Focus();
//When _colChild is null, the 3rd level is being expanded.
//ChildChildCellChecked is null
            if (childGrid._colChild == null)
            {             
                childGrid.CellChecked += new RowColEventHandler(ChildChildCellChecked);
            }

            OnAfterCollapse(e);

            // done
            return true;
        }
```

I would like to create the event, ChildCellChecked for the second level grid and ChildChildCellChecked for the 3rd level grid.

The grids are displaying correctly and can be expanded and collapse.  But when I click a Checkbox in the 3rd level grid, no event fires.

How do I associate an event handler with each level grid?

**UPDATE**

Using one of your code snippets to identify which level is being expanded, when the level is 2, the event ChildChildCellChecked is null.

I attached a document to show the screen shots during debug mode when the method Expand() is called during the first level call and during the second level call.

During the first level call of Expand(), ChildCellChecked is created.
During the second level call of Expand(), ChildChildCellChecked is null.  This results in an exception.

I cannot figure out why the delegate, ChildChildCellChecked is null during the second level call to Expand().

Screen shots attached can better show the error...
Taking 2 screen shots during debug mode.

FIRST GRID IS EXPANDED.
This is when the Parent grid is expanded to the first child.
You can see that BOTH events are defined.  Only ChildCellCheck has been created.
[image: Delegate to ChildCellChecked event during first call Expand()]
[image: Delegate to ChildChildCellChecked event during first call Expand()]

SECOND GRID IS EXPANDED.
When the first child grid is expanded to show the second level grid, this is the error:
[image: Error showing exception during second call Expand() to assign ChildChildCellChecked delegate]

Actually, both delegates are associated with their respective event methods during the first call to Expand().  During the second call to Expand(), both delegates are null.

I would have thought that when a child grid is created, regardless of the level, an event handler would be created for that child grid. That I would not need a second event handler for the second level grid.  When the Checkbox is clicked the event would be fired and within the event method you can determine which level of child grid fired the event.

Gloria

Answer (score 0):

As I have posted on your original post [here](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/create-datatree-that-can-toggle-between-2-tier-grid-and-3-tier-grid/#post-636036) :-

Refer the following comments:

- When a node is expanded, a child grid is added to the Controls collection of the parent. Similarly, when you collapse a row the child grid is removed from the Controls collection of the parent. While removing the child grid, the UserData for the HeaderGrid of the child is cleared. Thus, it would completely invalidate the event handler. This is why this snippet won’t work directly.
- If you expand all the rows before adding the event for each grid, it would work perfectly in cases when there is only one child per row. But, this wont work for more general case as the event for child would be called for all the children when only one child’s event is raised.
- As you have tried to implement, the best case scenario would definitely be to add the children’s event in the ExpandRow method of DataTree class. This way whenever a row is expanded, or a grid is created, the event handler is attached to the grid. A check can be performed to see if the current grid should be linked with event of 'child’ or 'child of child’. Refer the following snippet:

  ```
   int level = 0;
   C1FlexDataTree parent = new C1FlexDataTree();
   parent = childGrid;
   while (parent.Parent is C1FlexDataTree)
   {
   parent = parent.Parent as C1FlexDataTree;
   level++;
   }
   if (level ==  1)
   {
   childGrid.CellChecked += new RowColEventHandler(child_CellChecked);
   }
   else if (level == 2)
   {
   childGrid.CellChecked += new RowColEventHandler(childchild_CellChecked);
   }
  ```
- In your snippet you are checking if the UserData of the childGrid.Rows[row] is null. But the UserData of childGrid’s rows would always be null. Whenever a child grid is added to a grid, every row of the child grid is either collapsed or non expandable.
- TIP: If UserData is null for a row, this means the row is either collapsed or the row does not have any childGrid

  In the third point, we have created events for 'childs’ and 'childs of childs’. This wont create the event for the Parent grid. Therefore, you may have to add a snippet in the constructor of your DataTree class

  ```
   if (this.ParentGrid == this)
   {
        this.CellChecked+=new RowColEventHandler(Parent_CellChecked);
   }
  ```

***IMPORTANT***:

*All the child grids in a parent grid would be a DataTree. This is why the expanding a row of every child grid would also trigger ExpandRow method and eventually try to add the event handlers. Please take correct measure to ensure that the ExpandRow method for ChildGrid won’t add events like a parent grid. This can be ensured by checking the level of the childGrid. It is performed in Step 3.*

Answer (score 0):

Please note that every time a **DataTree** is created, all the embedded grids (which are child of the parent object)implement the same events. So it was not right to create a **ParentCheck**, **ChildCheck** and **ChildChildCheck** event all in the same **DataTree** class. This is why when we created **ParentCheck**, **ChildCheck** and **ChildChildCheck** events in a **DataTree** class, even the child execute **ChilChildCheck** event.

When a **CellChecked** event is created in a **DataTree** class, it is observed that all the grids inherit the **CellChecked** event. This was a very advantageous situation, where all we had to do was to identify the hierarchical level of the grid.

The implementation of checkboxes was the most imporatant part in placing the events. Since the checkboxes are nothing but a boolean column and not **glyphs** or **embedded** **controls**(as it is implemented in some of the samples online), checkboxes do not need to be linked individually with the event, and thus the **CellChecked** event can be implemented by overriding the base **CellChecked** event.

Please refer the following snippet:

```
protected override void OnCellChecked(RowColEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnCellChecked(e);
    // Access childs from a flex data tree
    if (this.Rows[e.Row].UserData != null)
    {
        C1FlexDataTree child = this.Rows[e.Row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
        foreach (Row childRow in child.Rows)
        {
            if (childRow.Index > 0)
            {
                childRow[1] = this.Rows[e.Row][1];
                if (childRow.UserData != null)
                {
                    C1FlexDataTree childchild = childRow.UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
                    foreach (Row childchildRow in childchild.Rows)
                    {
                        if (childchildRow.Index > 0)
                        childchildRow[1] = this.Rows[e.Row][1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Check the level of grid
    C1FlexDataTree parent = this;
    int level = 0;
    while (parent.Parent is C1FlexDataTree)
    {
        level++;
        parent = parent.Parent as C1FlexDataTree;
    }

    if (level == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am parent");
        // Place your code for ParentCellChecked here
    }
    else if (level == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am parent’s child");
        // Place your code for ChildCellChecked here
    }
    else if (level == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am parent’s child’s child");
        // Place your code for ChildChildCellChecked here
    }

}
```

Please note in the above snippet where **ParentCellChecked**, **ChildCellChecked** and **ChildChildCellChecked** must be implemented.

It is also possible to access the parent grid’s child’s child… and so on, if we have the access of the parent grid. This is depicted in the snippet below. Please note that child grids can’t be from the class where the parent grid is created. Use of this snippet is preferred in the DataTree class itself.

```
if (this.Rows[XthRow].UserData != null)
{
    C1FlexDataTree child = this.Rows[e.Row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
    foreach (Row childRow in child.Rows)
    {
        if (childRow.Index > 0)
        {
            // ALL THE CHILD’S ROW
            if (childRow.UserData != null)
            {
                C1FlexDataTree childchild = childRow.UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
                foreach (Row childchildRow in childchild.Rows)
                {
                    if (childchildRow.Index > 0)
                         // ALL THE CHILD’S CHILD’S ROW
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated your sample code that demonstrated the error.  Could you change the code I sent to show how your explanation would work?